# Apache Solr - Error Creating SolrCore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I just installed Tomcat 7 and Solr 4.9.1. Configured everything by following this guide.

http://eemglobal.com/2014/07/setup-rails-4-with-sunspot-gem-and-solr-4-7-in-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14/

Everyting works as excepted. But I cant create a new core, to use sunspot integration.

Here is the explantation about the issue.

[image]

Comment: Check the Tomcat log to see which exception got thrown. Tomcat might not have write access to the directory Solr keeps it cores in.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new core by cloning the folder collection1, then chooose the file core.properties and change name="Your folder".
P/S: http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/configuring-apache-solr-to-use-with-nopaccelerate/